# Check if redux action has been called with enzyme

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-mock-store

I am trying to test if a dispatch has been called from componentDidMount in my React Native project.
My problem is that I cant figure out how to check if autoLogin() has been called.

**test.js**

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

it('should be called once', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SplashScreen store={mockStore()} />).dive();
});
```

**index.js**

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.autoLogin();
    }
}

export default connect(null, { autoLogin })(SplashScreen);
```

Comment: Please add code of the `mockStore` function.

Comment: I have added the code you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that async/await was the solution to my problem.
Without await on wrapper.dive(), autoLogin would fire after my test had finished to run.

```
it('should be called once', async () => {
    const autoLogin = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<SplashScreen store={mockStore()} autoLogin={autoLogin} />);
    await wrapper.dive();
    expect(autoLogin.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```